# How to check 2DArray length on Lua?

Tags: multidimensional-array, lua

I'm having problems porting a program of mine from C# to Lua,

at some point, I need to check the length of the 2D array. In C# , I was using this :

```
testMap.GetLength(0)
```

or

```
testMap.GetLength(1)
```

for check the other dimension length. I've found solutions that use something like

```
#testmap
```

or similar, but I couldn't make it work at all.
Just in case, I'm working with this array :

```
`local testMap = {
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
};`
```

Comment: `#testMap` - number of demensions and `#testMap[1]` length of first array.

Comment: `#testMap -2 #testMap[1]` ? I can't make it work this way

Comment: Then you do not provide correct Lua code. May be you use some custom array class which redefine len operator. For your example i got `#testMap = 22` and ` #testMap[1]=12` as expected.

Comment: My bad! I misunderstood what you were telling me. It works! It's just what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @moteus said,

```
#testMap
```

for checking one dimension of the array and

```
#testMap[1]
```

for the other.

Comment: just make sure you know the restrictions of Lua's length operator! https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind: `t = { {1,2,3}, {4}, {5,6} }` will give `#t[1] --> 3`, `#t[2] --> 1`, `#t[3] --> 2`. It's not a fixed-size (matrix-like) 2D-array, it's an array of arrays that can each have different lengths (like in Java, in …). If you (accidentally) add/remove elements from some of the sub-arrays, you might get weird results. (Just keep this in mind if you ever have a strange bug that doesn't seem to make sense and somehow involves array lengths. You might have messed with the array shape & then it might be a good idea to temporarily check the sizes of _all_ sub-arrays.)

Answer (score 0):

Since `#testMap` is not giving you the result you want, I assume that you want to retrieve the total number of items of the inner arrays.

Here is how you can do this:

```
local testMap = {
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
};

-- Either like this:
print(#testMap*#testMap[1])

-- Or like this:
local total = 0
for i=1, #testMap do
    total = total + #testMap[i]
end
print(total)
```

You can try it here: https://repl.it/JBw1/0

Comment: Forivin, thanks for answering! But what moteus said was what I needed. But this piece of code will be of use too for me in later stages of the project, so thanks!